# Turning CSV data into nested JSON using OpenRefine

Tags: json, csv, openrefine

So I am trying to parse some weather data from a csv format and convert it to a nested JSON format. I currently have a large csv file with columns for: A Station ID, Month, and then 30 Columns for the data (per day). I have a header at the top with basic titles. I am trying to convert that into a json format where the Station ID is the key name, and inside of it there the months 1-12 are another key name, and inside of those each of the 30 days are displayed. I tried several online and donwlaodable CSV to JSON, and spent time playing with OpenRefine, but could not figure out how to take the Station id as the header and then nest the months, and then days. Here is a sample of the CSV data for reference : `Station Name,Month,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
AQW00061705,1,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,824C,825C,825C,825C,825C,825C,825C,825C,825C,825C,825C,826C,826C,826C`. 

There are 12 of these columns for every station id making this process especially difficult. If anyone has an experience with OpenRefine, or converting this type of structured data to JSON, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So writing an export template for this in OpenRefine is a bit of a pain, but can be done.

First in the OpenRefine project use the 'Edit Cells -> Blank Down' menu option on the Station Name column
Then go to Export and choose "Templating"
In the 'Prefix' section just put `[`
In the Row Template section put:

```
    {{if(row.record.fromRowIndex==row.index,if(row.record.fromRowIndex>0,",","")+"{\"Station Name\" :"+ jsonize(cells["Station Name"].value)+",","")}}
{{jsonize(cells["Month"].value)}}:{
{{forEach(row.columnNames[2,33],v,jsonize(v)+": "+jsonize(cells[v].value)+if(v!="31",",",""))}}
}{{if(cells["Month"].value!="12",",","")}}
{{if(row.index+1==row.record.toRowIndex,unescape("&#x7d;","html"),"")}}
```

Leave the Row Separator section blank
In the 'Suffix' section just put `]`

This should give you valid JSON like:

```
    [
  {
    "Station Name": "AQW00061705",
    "1": {
      "1": "824C",
      "2": "824C",
      "3": "824C",
      "4": "824C",
      "5": "824C",
```

etc.

The first '1' is the Month number, the subsequent "1": "824C" etc are the days and the readings

I've had to put a load of logic in here to get this to work - in theory a simpler version should have worked I think, but I saw some odd behaviour which led to invalid JSON - hence I've worked all the logic into the GREL within the template

Comment: Oh - and the use of `unescape("&#x7d;","html")` is because the templating mechanism doesn't like a closed curly brace within a GREL statement (it gets interpreted as part of the template for some reason - probably a bug). To avoid this I use the html encoding for `}` and then unescape it to leave the curly brace in the output

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Originally some of my blank cells were being outputted to null (making the json invalid) but after a quick transform of the cells, replacing them with a space character everything now works perfectly. There's no way I would have done it without that so thank you again :)

Comment: That's great Josh. If you have time to accept my answer that would be brilliant.

Comment: One more question actually. I was trying to do the same with another very similar file with *everything* the same except for data for every hour on every day, adding an extra column. This didn't seem to difficult except for now instead of having blank/null for the last days in the month that don't occur, these now rows are just left out.The data is now structured like so 'Station Name Month Day 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24'.  It seems trivial enough to change the [2,33] and '31', but how would you recommend going about this extra variable?[Thanks for the help]

Comment: This definitely gets more complex as you add to the hierarchy. To get this to work for the additional level of hierarchy you have here probably means rethinking the logic a bit. If you start by blanking down both Station Name and Month, then you can modify the code to only include these elements when these are present - the problem you hit is closing off these elements correctly - which in the above code I do by checking that we are at the last row in the 'record' - that only works for the Station Name column - you'd need to check for the end of the Month in a different way.